# JavaFX dynamically add buttons

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have fxml and controller class. In controller class I have `someAction()` method and in fxml I set `#someAction` as onAction for some Button. Now I want to create button not in fxml but dynamically from java code as `button = new Button()`. I still load fxml and I still have this controller with `someAction()` method. How can I set `someAction()` as onAction for my button? From java code I found only `setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent> eh)`. Is there a way to specify onAction in fxml-like style, just telling method name in controller class?

Answer (score 2):

One of the approaches can be:

```
private EventHandler<ActionEvent> yourHandler = new EventHandler<>() {
     public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
         // your logic
     }
};
```

then

```
button.setOnAction(yourHandler);
```

and

```
public void someAction(ActionEvent event) {
    yourHandler.handle(null);
}
```

Or in the same manner, define a business logic method and call it in two different action event handlers.

Comment: The second approach sounds more practical :)

Comment: @ItachiUchiha yes you are right. I just want also to show the usage of eventhandler here.